# how to collect the header title of all the reports in the application

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]
[image]
In this application : task is to click on each report link one by one and get the header title of the report from the report page.

so  it verifies that the report opens properly with data.

Since  there is no common x path in the all reports, thus
to capture the report heading i applied a generic x path : that gives me list of headings in the report page .....later i collected the heading with zero index, ie. the main header

Problem 1: there are few reports where : this x path has no significance, it locate nothing .....and in these report there exists view button ...clicking on view opens the report

Problem 2: there are few report where heading format is align either in right or left

According to my code : it is difficult to catch them ......there are 4 out 
of 80 such reports in a slot . where x path gives nothing as shown in 
attachment 
According to the code what logic should be applied to catch view ....
Using page Factory :

```
 @FindAll({
    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = ".//table//tr[1]/th")
 })

public List<WebElement> view_ReportPDf_page;

 List<WebElement> lis= namedreportviewlinks;     
 ///// TO get the report links within 
 int count=0;
 for (int j = 0; j < lis.size(); j++) {
 WebElement e2 = lis.get(j);
 ((JavascriptExecutor) 
 driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",e2);

 e2.click();
 for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
 {
 driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
 }
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 List<WebElement> lis2= ld.view_ReportPDf_page;
 for(WebElement headers:lis2)
{
headers=lis2.get(0);
System.out.println(headers.getText()+"--------------------"+count);
break;
}
driver.close();
 count++;
 for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
 {
  driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
 }
 }
 ld.Dnetsubcategoryreport_backbutton.click();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the View button is present under th tag then findElements() method can be used to check the presence of this button. If present, click on it else click on report link.
   e.g.

   if(driver.findElements(By.name("View")).size>0)
   {
   //logic to click on View button
   }
   else
   {
     //click on report link
   }
2. If the reports table is the only table on the page, then elements can be located using tagName as th. (NOTE: All report links should be under th tag then this approach can be applied.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: the two images shown above are : two different report pages... you can take them like suppose first time click on link 1 - top most report opens , next click on link 2 - second report with view link opens ...the difference between two is : one opens directly with text while another one opens with "view" link as shown , click on it further open the similar report in the same page. since i have created a generic x path to get the header, what logic should i implement in between to switch to view link

Comment: You can apply similar logic. Switch to newly opened page, verify if view link is present then click on it, else take text from newly opened report page.